# Window:Reload not updating package

Tags: github, package, atom-editor

I am somewhat new to Atom and am trying to fix bugs on one of the packages (terminal).  From what I have read in their [documentation](https://atom.io/docs/v0.91.0/your-first-package)... after I change a value I should run the [Window:Reload] command and then re-run the package (terminal).  I should then see my changes.

However, this is not working for me.  As a simple test I changed this line of code:

```
getTitle: -> 'Terminal'
```

to

```
getTitle: -> 'Show This Title'
```

I then ran the [Window:Reload] command and followed that up with the [Terminal] Command.  However, once Terminal loaded the title still showed as 'Terminal'.

Am I missing a step?  Or did I misread their documentation?  Curious as to why this isn't working.  Thanks for any advice / suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Should update if you are saving in ~/.atom/packages.
Reload can also be run with ctrl+alt+r